# I get redirected too many times only in wp-admin?

Tags: redirect, wp-redirect, nginx

I am trying to run wordpress in a subdirectory blog in my rails app, I used this nginx config as:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name _;

  passenger_ruby /usr/local/bin/ruby;
  passenger_enabled on;
  rails_env production;
  location ^~ /assets/ {
root /var/www/example/current/public;
    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;

  }

location /blog {
  root /var/www/example/current;
  index  index.html index.htm index.php;
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;

  location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
  }
}

}
```

My folders looks like this:

```
/rails_app/
/rails_app/blog/
/rails_app/blog/wp-admin/
```

where blog directory has wordpress files
I don't have any route starts with `blog` at rails app.

**There is no redirect loop for frontend, but only at wp-admin**

here in my wp-config.php I have:

```
define('WP_HOME','https://example.com/blog');
define('WP_SITEURL','https://example.com/blog');

$_SERVER['HTTPS']='on';
define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);
define('FORCE_SSL_LOGIN', true);
```

any idea? how to debug this issue?

Comment: Welcome to [wordpress.se]. I hope you find the answer(s) you are looking for. Our site is different from most - if you have not done so yet, consider checking out the [tour](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tour) and [help center](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help) to find out how things work.